# User control button

Tags: c#, winforms

i would like to create a custom control for my crud buttons. The user controls will have the following code.

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to Delete?", "Please Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        DeleteClick(sender, e); // this will read the code from GUI delete button

        if (DeleteResult.Success) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This record is deleted successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This record is deleted failed.");
        }
    }
```

}

My GUI

```
private void adminUserController_DeleteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repository.Delete(user);
}
```

Question:
1) What is the best way to pass the DeleteResult boolean result from GUI to User control?  How do i create an event for the delete button which can be hooked by the UI?
2) Do u think is good if i put my error logger code at the user control button?

Comment: You check the "result" of DeleteResult except there is no such variable in the posted code.  #1 How your attempting to do it is fine.  #2 Log errors in your main application not at the user control level.

Answer (score 1):

replace the call in your adminUserController_DeleteClick with a call to a new method (foo)

```
private DeleteResult foo(TypeOfUser user)
{
   return Repository.Delete(user);
}
```

and call foo instead of adminUserController_DeleteClick

foo will return the desired result

Comment: Hi, i think the adminUserController_DeleteClick should be an event. When user click on the delete button in the GUI form, it should be hooked with an event. I have no idea how to run the foo() when user click on the delete button which is a user control. Please advice thanks

Comment: @belinq ... i don't know if i understood you correctly. you have a button. on the click event of that button you have registered btnDelete_Click. inside that handler you want to call adminUserController_DeleteClick and get the return value of the Repository.Delete(user) call. not possible this way. you will either have to call Repository.Delete(user) directly, or wrap this call in another function (foo) that returns the desired value. so you can call foo either from your buttons click hanlder, or from adminUserController_DeleteClick

Comment: Sorry as my question is not clear to you. I have a UserControl which has 4 CRUD buttons. The `btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` is the event for the user control. I then drag the usercontrol out to my UI form. So whenever user click on the Delete button at UI Form, i need it to fire the event from the usercontrol first asking "Are you sure to delete", then fire the `Repository.Delete(user);` in UI Form, Then back to the UserControl to show whether it is successlly delete or not.

Comment: @belinq ... you should think about changing that design ... have a look at the MVC pattern: your user input events (click delete button) should not process data ... they should interact with a controller that updates your data model and the view of that model ... this makes sure that it is irrelevant which delete button a user has clicked

Comment: however, if you have to use this design for some reason, you could change that usercontrol to store the last value returned by repository.delete() in a property with a public getter, which can be accessed by your other function